# Splitting Ionic card in half. I want to show students on the right and the teachers on the left

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

This is what I currently have: https://gyazo.com/7b0c0d53beef6846545bece011332cd5 .  You can see that I have a lot of pictures next to each other, but I want to have 2 halves in the ionic card. On the topleft the groupname , bottom left the teachers and on the right side the studens in the group. I want it like this: https://gyazo.com/d5e71aa9cfe6de9f121ce236f951a6d7 .

#### HTML

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color ="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{ appName }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let group of groupData">
      <ion-card >
        <ion-item>
          <h2>{{ group.name }}</h2>

              <div class="pic" *ngFor="let student of group.students">
                <img [src]="student.avatar" />
              </div>
              <h3>{{group.students.length}}  Leerlingen</h3>

              <div class="pic" *ngFor="let teacher of group.teachers">
                <img [src]="teacher.avatar" />
              </div>
              <h3>{{group.teachers.length}} leerkrachten</h3>


          </ion-item>

      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>


</ion-content>
```

#### CSS

```
.pic{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ion-item, you can use div tag and set specifically half width of the content like so

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let group of groupData">
      <ion-card >
        <div class="left-content">
          <div class="pic" *ngFor="let teacher of group.teachers">
             <img [src]="teacher.avatar" />
          </div>
          <h3>{{group.teachers.length}} leerkrachten</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right-content">
          <h2>{{ group.name }}</h2>
          <div class="pic" *ngFor="let student of group.students">
              <img [src]="student.avatar" />
          </div>
          <h3>{{group.students.length}}  Leerlingen</h3>
        </div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**Css**

```
.left-content {
  width: 50%;
  float: 'left'
}
.right-content {
  width: 50%,
  float: 'right'
}
```

Comment: This is what happens whe I use this code https://gyazo.com/b12d578a1ec2b1eb03c095fcb1bae54c

Comment: See my updated answer. Try added float left and right

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid system

```
<ion-card >
  <ion-item>
    <h2>{{ group.name }}</h2>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <div class="pic" *ngFor="let student of group.students">
          <img [src]="student.avatar" />
        </div>
        <h3>{{group.students.length}}  Leerlingen</h3>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col col-6>
        <div class="pic" *ngFor="let teacher of group.teachers">
          <img [src]="teacher.avatar" />
        </div>
        <h3>{{group.teachers.length}} leerkrachten</h3>
      </ion-col>
    <ion-row>

  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: with this I get this: https://gyazo.com/180f666f03b8a638d63912a6f7d8e410 all the cards get in to each other. I've tried this already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this new modification if it fits

```
<ion-card >
      <ion-item>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6>
       <ion-row> <h2>{{ group.name }}</h2></ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <div class="pic" *ngFor="let student of group.students">
              <img [src]="student.avatar" />
            </div>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <h3>{{group.students.length}}  Leerlingen</h3>
           </ion-row>
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col col-6>
           <ion-row>
            <div class="pic" *ngFor="let teacher of group.teachers">
              <img [src]="teacher.avatar" />
            </div>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
            <h3>{{group.teachers.length}} leerkrachten</h3>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

         </ion-item>
        </ion-card>
```